# How to wait for few items in Queue before start consumer

Tags: python-3.x, queue, producer-consumer

I am implementing a Producing-Consuming pattern using Queue module from python3. The producer is byte streams via websocket, and the consumer plays audio in real-time. Since they have almost the same speed of producing/consuming data, the audio is choppy if the queue reaches size 0.

I want to start consumer only if there're at least n items in the queue (similar with having a buffer while playing video). How could I implement this properly? Will assigning global variables avoid race condition?

```
global queue
global warm_start = False

def produce():
    queue.put(data)
    if queue.qsize() > 5:
        warm_start = True

def consume():
   queue.get(data)

Thread(target=produce).start()
while True:
    if warm_start:
        Thread(target=consume).start()
```

Comment: 1. You should implement the buffer queue for this producer-consumer problem, using condition variable. 
2. Producer should signal the condition variable only when there are 3 or more items available in the buffer queue. This will wake up the consumer to consume the generate buffers.

Comment: @AshishKhurange: Thanks. How about checking queue.qsize() in the consumer?

Comment: You can keep on checking queue size in consumer. Just in case you want to see the usage of condition variable to implement thread safe buffer queue check this: https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/05/12/thread-safe-buffer-queue-python-code/